# seguimiento de posiciones en un ranking php

Tags: php

yo tengo un ranking y quiero ir marcando si está subiendo de posición o bajando o si se mantuvo, como se ve en este ejemplo.

[image: ranking]

> se me ocurría la idea de que podía ser agregando un campo en la tabla que guarde las posiciones de los usuarios pero no estoy seguro si se hace así o como es el tema

saludos